# What are the commands that you can use in the beginning of a sed command?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I initially learned to do `sed` search and replace like so:

```
sed -e 's/<stuff>/<replacement>/'
```

However I recently learned that these will do something different based on what command character you use at the beginning (instead of `s`). For example:

```
sed -e 'g/<stuff>/<??>/'
```

What are the different commands you can use at the beginning of a `sed` script, and what do they do?

Comment: Check out [Sed & Awk](http://sirpabs.ilahas.com/Oreillybookshelf/books/unix2/sedawk/index.htm), Chapters 5 and 6.

Answer (score 3):

I have made this answer a community-wiki post because it contains work that is
not my own. Feel free to contribute to this answer.

The letters you see are called commands. There are dozens of them. To fully
understand them, you must first understand a bit about `sed`'s syntax and
terminology. For an explanation of `sed`'s terminology, including the terms
`pattern space` and `hold space`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833714/the-concept-of-hold-space-and-pattern-space-in-sed) answer from StackOverflow.

sed syntax looks like this:

```
[address or range]command
```

You may run multiple commands in series by separating them with newlines or
semicolons (though, some commands must be separated by newlines).

There are three types of commands.

1. Those that do not accept addresses or ranges.
2. Those that accept either one address or no addresses.
3. Those that accept address ranges.

Below you will find a nearly-complete list of `sed` commands from the `sed(1)`
manpage. I'm working on providing better explanations for these commands.

**Zero- or one-address commands**

These are commands

- `=` - Print the current line number.
- `a \<text>` - Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
- `i \<text>` - Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
- `q [exit-code]` - Immediately quit the sed script without processing any more input, except that if auto-print is not disabled the  current pattern space will be printed.  The exit code argument is a GNU extension.
- `Q [exit-code]` - Immediately quit the sed script without processing any more input.  This is a GNU extension.
- `r filename` - Append text read from filename.
- `R filename` - Append  a  line  read from filename.  Each invocation of the command reads a line from the file.  This is a GNU extension.

**Address range commands**

- `b label` - Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
- `c \ text` - Replace theHere are a few (taken from the `sed(1)` manpage, formatted, and slightly modified): selected lines with text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
- `d` - Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
- `D` - If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued.  Otherwise, delete text in  the  pattern  space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.
- `h H` - Copy/append pattern space to hold space.
- `g G` - Copy/append hold space to pattern space.
- `l` - List out the current line in a ``visually unambiguous'' form.
- `l <width>` - List out the current line in a ``visually unambiguous'' form, breaking it at  characters.  This is a  GNU  extension.
- `n N` - Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.
- `p` - Print the current pattern space.
- `P` - Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space.
- `s/regexp/replacement/` - Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement. The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched,  and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.
- `t label` - If  a  `s///` command  has  done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command,  then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
- `T label` - If no `s///` command has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t  or  T  command,
  then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.  This is a GNU extension.
- `w filename` - Write the current pattern space to filename.
- `W filename` - Write the first line of the current pattern space to filename.  This is a GNU extension.
- `x` - Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.
- `y/source/dest/` - Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest.

For more information about these commands, see the sed [Texinfo manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo).

**A note on ranges**

Some sed commands accept addresses or address ranges. For example,

```
sed 1p
```

would print line number one of sed's input.

```
sed /foo/p
```

would print all lines containing the word `foo`.

```
sed /foo/,/bar/p
```

would print all lines from `foo` to `bar`. Note that this may match multiple times. For example,

```
$ cat file
foo
baz
bar
baz
foo
bar
$ sed -n /foo/,/bar/p
```

would print

```
foo
baz
bar
foo
bar
```